# Form fields are not being populated

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I have the following code and the template rendered is not displaying any input, code used is

**views.py**

```
@login_required
def settings(request, profile_type=None):
    context = {}

    initial_data = dict()
    setting_object = dict()
    settings = EmailEvent.objects.all()
    for setting in settings:
        tmp_settings_object = EmailSetting.objects.filter(user=request.user,   event=setting)
    if not tmp_settings_object:
        setting_object[setting], created = EmailSetting.objects.get_or_create(user=request.user, event=setting)
        initial_data[setting.name] = setting_object[setting].enabled
    else:
        setting_object[setting] = tmp_settings_object[0]
        initial_data[setting.name] = setting_object[setting].enabled

    email_settings_form = EmailSettingsForm(initial=initial_data)

    password_form = PasswordChangeForm()

    profile = request.user.get_profile().profile(request)
    if not profile:
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/signup/additional/')
    profile_type = profile.get_type().lower()

    user_info_form = UserInfoForm()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.POST.get('old_password'):
            password_form = PasswordChangeForm(request.POST)
            if password_form.is_valid():
                [cd, error] = password_form.clean_data(request.user)
                if error:
                messages.error(request, error)
                else:
                   request.user.set_password(password_form.cleaned_data['new_password'])
                   request.user.save()
                   messages.success(request, 'Your password has been changed.')
                   context['password_form'] = password_form
        else:
            user_info_form = UserInfoForm(request.POST, request.FILES, request=request)
            if user_info_form.is_valid():
                user_info_form.save(request.user, profile_type)
                messages.success(request, 'You have successfully updated your profile.')
                if request.is_ajax():
                    response = simplejson.dumps({"status": "Upload Success"})
                    return HttpResponse(response, mimetype='application/json')
                return HttpResponseRedirect(request.POST.get('next', '/profile/' + profile_type + '/' + request.user.username + '/'))
    else:
      initial = {}
      initial['first_name'] = request.user.first_name
      initial['last_name'] = request.user.last_name
      initial['email'] = request.user.email
      if profile:
          initial['phone_number'] = profile.phone_number 
          initial['about'] = profile.about
          initial['country'] = profile.country
          initial['job_title'] = profile.job_title
          firms = profile.works_firms()
          if firms:
            context['firm'] = firms[0]
          if profile_type == "investor":
            initial['investor_type'] = profile.investor_type
      user_info_form = UserInfoForm(initial=initial)
      context['user_info_form'] = user_info_form
      context['profile_type'] = profile_type
      context['content_type'] = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(profile)
      #end of edit profile
      try:
         context['subscription'] = Subscription.objects.get(user=request.user)
      except ObjectDoesNotExist:
         None

if request.user.get_profile().has_both_profiles():
    investor_profile = InvestorProfile.objects.get(user=request.user)
    investor_settings, created = InvestorPrivacySetting.objects.get_or_create(profile=investor_profile)
    context['investor_form'] = InvestorPrivacySettingForm(prefix='investor', instance=investor_settings)
    manager_profile = ManagerProfile.objects.get(user=request.user)
    manager_settings, created = ManagerPrivacySetting.objects.get_or_create(profile=manager_profile)
    context['manager_form'] = ManagerPrivacySettingForm(prefix='manager', instance=manager_settings)
    investor_activity_settings = []
    for action in Action.objects.all().exclude(privacy_settings_text__isnull=True).exclude(privacy_settings_text=''):
        setting, created = ActivityPrivacySetting.objects.get_or_create(profile_content_type=ContentType.objects.get_for_model(investor_profile), profile_object_id=investor_profile.id, action=action)
        investor_activity_settings.append(setting)
    context['investor_activity_settings'] = investor_activity_settings
    manager_activity_settings = []
    for action in Action.objects.all().exclude(privacy_settings_text__isnull=True).exclude(privacy_settings_text=''):
        setting, created = ActivityPrivacySetting.objects.get_or_create(profile_content_type=ContentType.objects.get_for_model(manager_profile), profile_object_id=manager_profile.id, action=action)
        manager_activity_settings.append(setting)
    context['manager_activity_settings'] = manager_activity_settings
elif request.session['role'] == 'investor':
    investor_profile = InvestorProfile.objects.get(user=request.user)
    investor_settings, created = InvestorPrivacySetting.objects.get_or_create(profile=investor_profile)
    context['investor_form'] = InvestorPrivacySettingForm(prefix='investor', instance=investor_settings)
    investor_activity_settings = []
    for action in Action.objects.all().exclude(privacy_settings_text__isnull=True).exclude(privacy_settings_text=''):
        setting, created = ActivityPrivacySetting.objects.get_or_create(profile_content_type=ContentType.objects.get_for_model(investor_profile), profile_object_id=investor_profile.id, action=action)
        investor_activity_settings.append(setting)
    context['investor_activity_settings'] = investor_activity_settings
elif request.session['role'] == 'manager':
    manager_profile = ManagerProfile.objects.get(user=request.user)
    manager_settings, created = ManagerPrivacySetting.objects.get_or_create(profile=manager_profile)
    context['manager_form'] = ManagerPrivacySettingForm(prefix='manager', instance=manager_settings)
    manager_activity_settings = []
    for action in Action.objects.all().exclude(privacy_settings_text__isnull=True).exclude(privacy_settings_text=''):
        setting, created = ActivityPrivacySetting.objects.get_or_create(profile_content_type=ContentType.objects.get_for_model(manager_profile), profile_object_id=manager_profile.id, action=action)
        manager_activity_settings.append(setting)
    context['manager_activity_settings'] = manager_activity_settings
context['PRIVACY_LEVEL_CHOICES'] = PRIVACY_LEVEL_CHOICES
context['user_info_form'] = user_info_form
context['email_form'] = email_settings_form
context['password_form'] = password_form
context['current'] = 'settings'
context['has_linked_in_profile'] = LinkedInProfile.objects.filter(user=profile.user).exists()
context['has_facebook_profile'] = FacebookProfile.objects.filter(user=profile.user).exists()
context['tag_types'] = TagType.objects.all()

return render_to_response('settings/base.html', context, context_instance=RequestContext(request))



@login_required
def email_settings(request):
    settings = EmailEvent.objects.all()
    setting_object = dict()
    for setting in settings:
        setting_object[setting], created = EmailSetting.objects.get_or_create(user=request.user, event=setting)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        email_settings_form = EmailSettingsForm(request.POST)
        if email_settings_form.is_valid():
           for setting in settings:
               if email_settings_form.cleaned_data.get(setting.name) !=    setting_object.get(setting).enabled:
               setting_object[setting].enabled = email_settings_form.cleaned_data.get(setting.name, False)
               setting_object[setting].save()
           messages.success(request, 'Email settings have been saved')
           return HttpResponseRedirect('/account/settings/#settings-email')
    else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/account/settings/#settings-email')
```

**forms.py**

```
class EmailSettingsForm(forms.Form):
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(EmailSettingsForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    settings = EmailEvent.objects.all()
    for setting in settings:
        self.fields[setting.name] = forms.BooleanField(required=False)
```

**template.html**

```
<form method="POST" action="/account/settings/email/">
    <section class="main">{% csrf_token %}
         <h4>Email me when</h4>

        <p>{{ email_form.dormant_user }}
            <label for="id_same_tag_added" class="checkbox-label">I haven't been to the site in a while.</label>
        </p>
        <p>{{ email_form.same_tag_added }}
            <label for="id_same_tag_added" class="checkbox-label">Someone adds the same interests.</label>
        </p>
        <p>{{ email_form.message_received }}
            <label for="id_message_received" class="checkbox-label">I receive a message.</label>
        </p>
        <p>{{ email_form.investment_verification }}
            <label for="id_investment_verification" class="checkbox-label">I have new investments to verify.</label>
        </p>
        <p>{{ email_form.fund_introduction }}
            <label for="id_fund_introduction" class="checkbox-label">I receive a new introduction.</label>
        </p>
        <p>{{ email_form.employment_verification }}
            <label for="id_employment_verification" class="checkbox-label">I receive new employment requests.</label>
        </p>
        <p>{{ email_form.friend_request }}
            <label for="id_friend_request" class="checkbox-label">I receive a new connection request.</label>
        </p>
        <p>{{ email_form.connection_accepted }}
            <label for="id_friend_request" class="checkbox-label">I have a new connection accepted.</label>
        </p>{% if role == 'manager' %}
        <p>{{ email_form.management_verification }}
            <label for="id_management_verification" class="checkbox-label">Email me when I have new management positions to verify.</label>
        </p>{% endif %}
        <p>{{ email_form.weekly_newsletter }}
            <label for="id_weekly_newsletter" class="checkbox-label">Send me weekly newsletter.</label>
        </p>
        <input type="hidden" name="next" value="/account/settings/">
    </section>
    <section class="bottom">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-large" name="basic"> <i class="icon-ok"></i> Save changes</button>
    </section>
</form>
```

**rendered template**

```
<form method="POST" action="/account/settings/email/">
    <section class="main">
        <div style='display:none'>
            <input type='hidden' name='csrfmiddlewaretoken' value='####################' />
        </div>
         <h4>Email me when</h4>

        <p>
            <label for="id_same_tag_added" class="checkbox-label">I haven't been to the site in a while.</label>
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="id_same_tag_added" class="checkbox-label">Someone adds the same interests.</label>
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="id_message_received" class="checkbox-label">I receive a message.</label>
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="id_investment_verification" class="checkbox-label">I have new investments to verify.</label>
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="id_fund_introduction" class="checkbox-label">I receive a new introduction.</label>
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="id_employment_verification" class="checkbox-label">I receive new employment requests.</label>
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="id_friend_request" class="checkbox-label">I receive a new connection request.</label>
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="id_friend_request" class="checkbox-label">I have a new connection accepted.</label>
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="id_management_verification" class="checkbox-label">Email me when I have new management positions to verify.</label>
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="id_weekly_newsletter" class="checkbox-label">Send me weekly newsletter.</label>
        </p>
        <input type="hidden" name="next" value="/account/settings/">
    </section>
    <section class="bottom">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-large" name="basic"> <i class="icon-ok"></i> Save changes</button>
    </section>
</form>
```

the rendered template has no input from {{ email_form.fields }}, can any one tell whats possibly wrong?

Comment: You need to shorten the code. You can atleast shrink the templates (expected & actual). Also, the indentation in the .py file is incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you defined your "context" as a regular python dictionary. You need to use:

```
from django.template import Context

context = Context()
```

Comment: from django.template import Context